# Printing and separating columns in awk

Tags: awk

I have file (VCF) as like this

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total Depth">
##FILTER=<ID=q10,Description="Quality below 10">
##FILTER=<ID=s50,Description="Less than 50% of samples have data">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
##FORMAT=<ID=HQ,Number=2,Type=Integer,Description="Haplotype Quality">
#CHROM POS     ID        REF ALT    QUAL FILTER INFO    FORMAT      NA00001
Chr02   259 .   A   .   20  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:1:0,1:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,26,23,75,33,33,33,47,52,49:23
Chr02   260 .   C   .   13  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:1:0,0:0,1:0,0:0,0:24,0,70,17,25,49,43,25,25,44:16
Chr02   261 .   C   .   13  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:1:0,0:0,1:0,0:0,0:24,0,194,18,25,49,44,25,25,45:16
Chr02   262 .   C   A   21  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/1:1:0,0:0,1:0,0:0,0:387,0,342,348,25,368,376,25,25,368:25
Chr02   263 .   C   .   24  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:0,0:1,1:0,0:0,0:541,0,529,495,29,556,508,29,29,499:29
Chr02   264 .   A   .   31  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:1,1:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,280,192,317,36,36,36,178,302,219:36
Chr02   265 .   G   C   25  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/1:2:0,0:0,0:1,1:0,0:255,414,0,328,284,29,284,29,351,29:29
Chr02   266 .   A   .   31  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:1,1:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,281,323,440,36,36,36,209,309,315:36
Chr02   267 .   C   .   24  .   .   GT:DP:A:C:G:T:PP:GQ 0/0:2:0,0:1,1:0,0:0,0:595,0,541,481,28,567,512,28,28,512:
```

And I just need to print first and second row as like this

```
 Chr02:259-259
 Chr02:260-260
 Chr02:261-261
 Chr02:262-262
 Chr02:263-263
 .
 .
 .
 Chr02:267-267
```

I have tried with this command in awk

```
awk '{ OFS = ":" }{print$1,$2,$2}' input.txt
```

But it is not worked for me

Comment: Assuming you do not want to print rows starting with `#` you can use
`awk '!/^#/{print $1":"$2"-"$2}' input.txt`

Comment: wrt `print first and second row` - those are columns (aka fields) you're printing, not rows (aka lines or records). Also "it's not working for me" is the worst possible problem description as it gives us no information to help you fix your code. Just like when you take your car to a mechanic you have to tell us in what way it's not working for us to be able to help you fix it - no output, wrong output, error messages, something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^Chr/{print $1":"$2"-"$2}' Input_file
```

OR in case you want to look for lines which are starting with Chr followed by digits then try following.

```
awk '/^Chr[0-9]+/{print $1":"$2"-"$2}' Input_file
```

OR in case you want to leave only commented lines then try following:

```
awk '!/^#/{print $1":"$2"-"$2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking condition if line starts from Chr(in first solution) OR Chr followed by digits(in 2nd solution) OR line doesn't start from `#`(3rd solution) then print 1st field colon 2nd field dash 2nd field.